# Where is the email template for the new user, created by admin from cms. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, cms

I have to make an email template, that is sent when the administrator creates a new account. I made a template, but in cms I can't see where it is used. I was looking for it in:
- stores/configuration/customers/customers configuration 
- stores/configuration/customers/advanced/admin

In vendor this template is called "new_user_notification.html".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check Below Section and select the required template which is created by you.
Stores=>Configuration=>Customers Tab=>Customer Configuration => Create New Account Options Section

Comment: I have already changed templates there, they don't work. This is when the administrator creates a new user.

Comment: Are you still receiving the default email templates? did you clear the cache.?

Comment: I clear all 16 caches, flush magento caches and i click button flush static files. 
Maybe I have some error that does not overwrite the default template. 
Is it possible that these are adminhtml templates and therefore do not overwrite?